# Frequent TcpCommunicationSpi error in Gridgain Client node

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We have 3 node Gridgain cluster in Kubernetes. Gridgain version is 8.8.8 and client nodes written in java given following error frequently. As I sew data inserted and SQL queries are working. What is the reason for this and is this effected to data because we use persistence enabled gridgain server. So data loss should not possible.

```
2021-10-01 06:07:45:113 ERROR TcpCommunicationSpi: Failed to read data from remote connection (will wait for 2000ms).
    org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to select events on selector.
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2300)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1891)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
            at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.register(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:204)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2109)
            ... 3 common frames omitted
```